# Site Pages Report

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, aspx, wiki-pages, web-analytics

I want to be able to pull a report in my subsite that will list all of my pages (wiki) in my site contents and the direct link to the page. Does this exist in SharePoint analytics reports?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to do it is using PowerShell to loop through all your subsites and display all the pages in the Site Pages library. Here is thread with a script which fits your requirements. You can change a bit to get other properties you may need.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/201bfe65-f9d3-4942-bc8a-7ae1b214b56d/how-to-get-a-list-of-subsites-and-all-the-pages-for-a-web-application?forum=sharepointadminprevious